# issue after update Flutter project to Flutter 2.0

Tags: flutter, dart, provider

After update to Flutter 2.0, these files have issues with the methods inheritFromElement,inheritFromWidgetOfExactType.

[image]

Comment: I got a some error today. Tried to downgrade as well as switch to another channel but it did not work.

Comment: Try a newer version of the `provider` package.

Comment: I updated my provider package to latest version and its worked for me.

Comment: I am using flutter_bloc and I have updated flutter_bloc package still its having the same problem